# Build failed: No module named virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

I have a Python 3.7 GCP App Engine project. Everything works well normally. For the past hour, however, I have not been able to deploy a new version of my app. I keep the same kind of Internal error. What can I do to resolve this? According to the VCS used, I have not changed anything since the last commit.

The command I run is the same as always: `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project=my-project-name`

Here is the output:

> Beginning deployment of service [default]...
>   #============================================================#
>
> #= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 =#
>   #============================================================#
>
> File upload done.
>
> Updating service [default]
>
> ...
>   ............................failed. ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error
>
> Response: [9] Cloud build 111fffff-1111-2222-cbaf-edcba154321f status:
>
> FAILURE. Error ID: 6C9DE5CE. Error type: InternalError. Error message:
>
> `create_virtualenv` had stderr output: /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7:
>
> No module named virtualenv
>
> error: `create_virtualenv` returned code: 1.

Comment: I actually just ran into that tonight. I'm wondering if there's a bug in the Google Infrastructure.

Comment: Appears to be working again. I made no changes and just attempted a deploy again. It now works.

Comment: @Samuel Are you still experiencing this issue?